# php preg_match only numbers, letters and dot

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have been searching for 2 hours now and I still don't get it. 
I need to evaluate the input of the account name. That can ONLY contain numbers (`0-9`), letters (`a-z` and `A-Z`) and the dot (`.`).

Everything else is forbidden. So, no underscore (`_`), plus (`+`) and so on.

Valid accounts should look like, e.g.:

```
john.green
luci.mayer89
admin
```

I tried many preg_match/regex examples but I don't get it working. Whenever I do `echo preg_match(...)` I get `1` as `true`.

```
$accountname = "+_#luke123*";
echo preg_match("/[a-z0-9.]/i", $accountname);

//--> gives back 1 as true
```

In addition, it would be great to control that the account name starts with at least 2 letters or numbers and ends with at least 1 letter or number - but I am far, far away from that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use anchors and a quantifier:

```
echo preg_match("/^[a-z0-9.]+$/i", $accountname);
```

Your string `+_#luke123*` contains a letter and a number, thus there is a match. If we tell the engine to only match the whole string from beginning (`^`) to end (`$`), we'll make sure this will not match. `+` ensures we capture not just 1, but all characters.

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fL6qY7/2), now there is no match!

**EDIT**:
Since you also need to check these conditions:

> string must start with 2 or more letters or numbers and end with 1 or
>   more letters or numbers

I can suggest this `^[a-z0-9]{2,}[a-z0-9.]*[a-z0-9]+$` regex (must be used with `i` option) that means:

- Starts with 2 or more letters or numbers
- then follow any number of digits, letters or periods
- and ends in 1 or more letters or numbers.

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/fL6qY7/3)

Comment: perfect!!! thx for the explanation! now i understand the meaning of ^ and $. 
can you also help me with the second part? string must start with 2 or more letters or numbers and end with 1 or more letters or numbers (e.g. lu.b is good but "a." or ".abc" must fail)?

Comment: Maybe, this `^[a-z0-9]{2,}[a-z0-9.]*[a-z0-9]+$` (must be used with `i` option) is what you are looking for? Starts with 2 or more letters or numbers, then any number of numbers, letters or period; and ends in 1 or more letters or numbers. https://regex101.com/r/fL6qY7/3

Comment: i tried this one and it seems to be working: `^[a-z0-9]{2}[a-z0-9.]{0,}[a-z0-9]{1}+$`